# How to declare multiple kwargs for function using multiple function from same library inside it

Tags: python, plotly, keyword-argument

I know there are similar questions but still could not figure it out the proper syntax for this issue.

I would like to define a function under a library created by myself based on plotly functions.
The function i would like to create needs multiple kwargs to be declared for using them separate function under my function.Below is my failing example code

```
def plotly_overlaid_histogram(self,series1,series2,**{**kwargs1,**kwargs2}):
    self.series1=series1
    self.series2=series2
    fig=go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=series1))
    fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=series2))
    fig.update_layout(**kwargs1)
    fig.update_traces(**kwargs2)
    fig.show()
```

I also try first line like followings but did not help either

```py
def plotly_overlaid_histogram(self,series1,series2,**{**kwargs1,**kwargs2}):
    pass
```

```py
def plotly_overlaid_histogram(self,series1,series2,**kwargs1,**kwargs2):
    pass
```

Comment: How would Python know which keywords belong to ``kwargs1`` and which belong to ``kwargs2``? What if a single keyword "belongs" to both?

Answer (score 0):

As @MisterMiyagi mentioned in the comments, by using that syntax, Python wouldn't know which keyword arguments go with which set, e.g., when you unpack the dictionary `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}` in a function call, all the function sees is `a=1, b=2, c=3` as keyword arguments.

## Solution 1: do it differently

For your case, I suggest making the traces and layout keyword-only arguments, and type hint them as `dict`:

```py
def plotly_overlaid_histogram(self, series1, series2, *, layout: dict, traces: dict) -> go.Figure:
    ...
    fig.update_layout(**layout)
    fig.update_traces(**traces)
```

Then just pass separate "kwargs" dictionaries when calling:

```py
layout = dict(title="hello world")
traces = dict(marker_color="pink")
obj.plotly_overload_histogram(series1, series2, layout=layout, traces=traces)
```

Or whatever.

## Solution 2: if you really want to stick with your current interface

Another option is to use `go.Figure.update()` and rework your function a little bit. In order to update traces using `go.Figure.update()` you need to pass a list of dictionaries under the keyword `"data"`.

```py
fig = go.Figure(...)  # create some figure with multiple traces

traces = [{"opacity": 0.2}]*2  # because there are two traces
layout = dict(title="hello world")
update_dict = dict(layout=layout, data=traces)

fig.update(**update_dict)
```

And now you can redo your function signature:

```py
def plotly_overlaid_histogram(self, series1, series2, **update_dict) -> go.Figure:
    ...
    fig.update(**update_dict)
```

Just making sure to construct your update dictionary properly.

Of course, if all you're doing is passing a keyword argument dictionary to an inner function, you don't really need to use the unpacking operator in the signature, just pass your keyword arguments as a dictionary:

```py
def plotly_overlaid_histogram(self, series1, series2, update_dict) -> go.Figure:
    ...
    fig.update(**update_dict)
```

### Clarification

To clarify, you'd build your `update_dict` outside the function call, and then pass it as a dictionary (similar to how you were doing before), so:

```py
traces_kwargs = dict(opacity=0.2)  # whatever kwargs you WOULD'VE passed to fig.update_traces()

data = [traces_kwargs]*2  # because there are two traces in this case
layout = dict(title="hello world")  # whatever kwargs you WOULD'VE passed to fig.update_layout()

update_dict = dict(layout=layout, data=data)  # package all your 'kwargs' together

obj.plotly_overlaid_histogram(series1, series2, update_dict)  # call your function
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention @blorgan.Since i am creating a library i think it would better to declare it somewhere outside the function because i will probably use it again with another function that i will create.So If i would like to stick solution 2 , is there an easy way copy all kwargs of update_layout() and update_traces() of go.Figure()i check some packages but seems all refere somewhere else :) :(

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Solution 2 allows you to pass an `update_dict` of all the keyword arguments necessary for updating traces and layout of any figure.